# How to read the newcommand syntax for the \cventry item using awesome-cv?

Tags: macros, awesome-cv

I am trying to compile my CV using awesome-cv with overleaf. There is one position in my CV where I would like to go directly to the description leaving out both (i) position and (ii) period. Therefore, I would need to re-define \cventry. My general problem is that I do not exactly know how to read the command/syntax of it. Thus, would somebody be so nice and "translate" the below command (starting at \ifempty) into proper English? That would be very helpful and much appreciated. Thank you!

```
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
    \fi
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil, welcome to TeX.SE. Can you please post a complete MWE, not just a snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% defining a command of 5 arguments not allowed to have pararaph ends.
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{%
% probably missing \par here
  \vspace{-2.0mm}% negative space, missing % here
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}% set tabular spacing to 0, missing % here
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}% set extra vertical tabular spacing to 0, missing % here
  % two column tabular spanning full text width (L and R defined elsewhere)
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{\textwidth - 4.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
%
% if 2nd and 3rd argument are empty (\ifempty defined elsewhere)
    \ifempty{#2#3}
% if no #2 or #3 then set #1 and #4 using the commands
% \entrypositionstyle and \entrydatestyle  defined elsewhere
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
% else if #2 or #3 are non empty set #2 and #3 using
% \entrytitlestyle and \entrylocationstyle (defined elsewhere) on one row of the table
% then set #1 and #4 on a second row.
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
%
% Now test if #5 is empty (using tex primitives rather than \ifempty macro)
    \if\relax\detokenize{#5}\relax\else
% if #5 is non empty make a spanning entry containing #5 formatted with \descriptionstyle 
        \multicolumn{2}{L{\textwidth}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}}
    \fi
% end the tabular
  \end{tabular*}% % missing here
}
```

Comment: thank you. Your comment has helped me to adjust the code. However, a couple of new problems emerged. I opened another thread for it. Thank you again.